# Data binding failing when trying to bind from MainWindow code-behind to UserControl code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

My MainWindow uses the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I'm using the OnPropertyChanged function that I've been using for a while, which works.
In my MainWindow code-behind I have this:

```
public ObservableCollection<bool> MwOc { get; set; }

private bool _mwBool;
public bool MwBool { get { return _mwBool; } set { _mwBool = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MwOc = new ObservableCollection<bool>();

    MwOc.Add(false);
    MwBool = true;

    Console.WriteLine("MwOc:   " + MwOc.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("MwBool: " + MwBool);

    DataContext = this;
}
```

All my MainWindow xaml does is this:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="Control" UcOc="{Binding MwOc}" UcBool="{Binding MwBool}" />
```

My UserControl has two dependency properties: `UcOc` an `ObservableCollection<bool>` and `UcBool` a `bool`
Here is my UserControl code:

```
public ObservableCollection<bool> UcOc
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<bool>)GetValue(UcOcProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UcOcProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UcOcProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("UcOc", typeof(ObservableCollection<bool>), typeof(UserControl1));

public bool UcBool
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(UcBoolProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UcBoolProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UcBoolProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("UcBool", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1));

public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UcOc = UcOc ?? new ObservableCollection<bool>();

    DataContextChanged += (o, e) => { Console.WriteLine("DataContextChanged"); Print(); };
}

public void Print()
{
    UcOc = UcOc ?? new ObservableCollection<bool>();
    Console.WriteLine("UcOc:   " + UcOc.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("UcBool: " + UcBool);
}
```

My UserControl xaml is empty (just has the default `<Grid></Grid>`)

The output of this program is

```
MwOc:   1
MwBool: True
DataContextChanged
UcOc:   0
UcBool: False
```

How should I update the UserControl properties when its DataContext changes?

Comment: Edit code and add two dependency properties for better help you...

Comment: Right after `DataContextChanged` being fired, the bound property may not be updated yet. You should handle the event `TargetUpdated` of the `UserControl` instead. However not sure why you want to get the values in `DataContextChanged` event handler.

Comment: I was only checking the `DataContextChanged` event handler because I assumed the values would be updated at that point. I added in a `TargetUpdated` event handler to the `UserControl`, but it is never triggered.

Comment: looks like you need to set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` of the Binding to `true`. e.g: instead of `UcOc="{Binding MwOc}"`, you need `UcOc="{Binding MwOc, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true}"`

Comment: yes. I'm tested this way UcOc="{Binding MwOc, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true}" fire TargetUpdated event.

Comment: @Hopeless Please add your comment as an answer so I may accept it. For some reason the`DataContextChanged` handler was interfering with `MwOc` being updated. That is, when the `DataContextChanged` handler was still being subscribed to, `MwOc` was not updating the UserControl. But it works without the `DataContextChanged` handler.

Comment: I think you may want to add your own answer, I really prefer commenting to answering unless the answer is too long or the problem is quite interesting. I believe you can give more explanation than what I can (at least you've experienced your issue while I almost tried  suggesting based on general understanding).

Answer (score 1):

In the MainWindow xaml, the bindings need the `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` property set to true.
Instead of:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="Control" UcOc="{Binding MwOc}" UcBool="{Binding MwBool}" />
```

use:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="Control" UcOc="{Binding MwOc, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true}" UcBool="{Binding MwBool, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true}" />
```

In the UserControl, subscribing to the `DataContextChanged` event also causes the binding to fail on the `ObservableCollection<bool>` but not the `bool`. For currently unknown reasons.